# Filter related model django

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I am building the example django polls application. I want to exclude all polls, which have no choices. For that I have to access the related choices objects:

```
return Question.objects.filter(
pub_date__lte=timezone.now()
).exclude(
    choice_set__count=0
).order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
```

But this query results in a field error:

> Cannot resolve keyword 'choice_set' into field. Choices are: choice, id, pub_date, question_text

How can I query related models from the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `Choice` model set the `related_name` to the `Question` foreign key.
Example:

```
class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='choices')
    # other code..
```

And then your query should be something like that:

```
return (Question.objects
        .filter(pub_date__lte=timezone.now(),
                choices__isnull=False)
        .order_by('-pub_date')[:5])
```

**Note**: There is no `__count' lookup. If you want to rely on counts then check the [docs on this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset).

docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name

Answer (score 2):

To filter against a related model, you just use the lower-case model name - you can see that `choice` is one of the available fields.

However, this still won't work; there is no `__count` attribute to filter against. You can add one by using annotations, but there is a simpler way: compare against `None`:

```
.exclude(choice=None)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `_set` only applies when you are using that to retrieve the related model outside of the queryset, instead, as the error suggests, you can just use `choice`

```
.exclude(choice__isnull=True)
```